# Maven build using/allocating huge amount of memory

Tags: linux, memory, gwt, maven-2, maven

I have a decent sized GWT (Google Web Toolkit) project that is built using Apache Maven. The build process involves generating 8 rpms and 2 wars.

I'm trying to build the project on a remote virtual server, running CentOS 5.2 as a guest OS. Since the guest OS can't use swap space, I am having to allocate a huge amount of memory to the box for it to build, otherwise I get a `java could not allocate memory error (error=12)`. The build fails if there is under 7GB free. I suspect that most of this 7GB is never used, but is allocated for some reason.

At the end of the build the output reads: `[INFO] Final Memory: 178M/553M`

I have `MAVEN_OPTS` set to `-Xms256m -Xmx1024M`

I'm not sure how to make the maven build use less memory.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Can't say without looking at your logs, but the GWT compiler requires a lot of memory. Can you make sure that it's not the problem? Also you can enable JMX and use JVisualVM to see the memory usage of the maven and GWT compiler processes. RPM building usually doesn't take much memory.

Answer (score 4):

Note that forking plugins like the maven gwt plugin (and maven surefire) uses memory that is "outside" the total that is reported by the maven execution. I would recommend corrolating OS-level process sizes with the output from "jps -lv" to find out which fork is stealing all your memory.

If, for instance, for some reason the forked process does not terminate it would get very crowded, very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

That memory indicates it only ever needed a max of 553M, so the setting in MAVEN_OPTS is already above what you need. Are you saying you want to use less than that, or are you currently getting an error?